# Android, parsing issue with a xml file

Tags: android, xml-parsing, nullpointerexception, saxparser

I'm trying to parse this: [xml's url](http://sourcecode.net46.net/android/xml/tecnologies.xml)
By following this tutorial [Android XML Parsing Tutorial - Using SAXParser](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser), I tried to modify the source code but I get the next error:

```
11-17 20:04:38.072: I/System.out(13247): Error: null
11-17 20:04:38.072: D/AndroidRuntime(13247): Shutting down VM
11-17 20:04:38.082: W/dalvikvm(13247): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409951f8)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.net46.sourcecode.android.lectorxml2/net.net46.sourcecode.android.lectorxml2.LectorXML2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at net.net46.sourcecode.android.lectorxml2.LectorXML2Activity.onCreate(LectorXML2Activity.java:36)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
11-17 20:04:38.122: E/AndroidRuntime(13247):    ... 11 more
```

Thats my LogCat when the emulator runs. The three modified source code classes from the original tut now are: LectorXML2Activity.java, Lista.java, LecturaXML.java, here's the code:

```
//Lista.java
package net.net46.sourcecode.android.lectorxml2;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Lista {
private ArrayList<String> nombre = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> pagina = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> categoria = new ArrayList<String>();
public void setNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre.add(nombre);
}
public ArrayList<String> getNombre(){
    return this.nombre;
}

public void setPagina(String pagina){
    this.pagina.add(pagina);
}   
public ArrayList<String> getPagina(){
    return this.pagina;
}

public void setCategoria(String categoria){
    this.categoria.add(categoria);
}
public ArrayList<String> getCategoria(){
    return this.categoria;
}
}


//LecturaXML.java
package net.net46.sourcecode.android.lectorxml2;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
public class LecturaXML extends DefaultHandler{
public static Lista lista = null;
private Boolean elementoActual;
private String valorActual = null;
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String nombreLocal,
                         String qNombre, Attributes atributos)
throws SAXException{
    elementoActual = true;
    if(nombreLocal.equals("tecnologias")){
        lista = new Lista();
    }else if(nombreLocal.equals("pagina")){
        String attr = atributos.getValue("categoria");
        lista.setCategoria(attr);
    }
}   
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String nombreLocal, String qNombre)
throws SAXException{
    elementoActual = false;
    if(nombreLocal.equalsIgnoreCase("nombre")){
        lista.setNombre(valorActual);
    }else if(nombreLocal.equalsIgnoreCase("pagina")){
        lista.setPagina(valorActual);
    }
}
@Override
public void characters(char[]ch, int inicio, int longitud)
throws SAXException{
    if(elementoActual){
        valorActual = new String(ch,inicio,longitud);
        elementoActual = false;
    }
}

public static Lista getLista(){
    return lista;
}
public static void setLista(Lista lista){
    LecturaXML.lista = lista;
}
}



//LectorXML2Activity.java
package net.net46.sourcecode.android.lectorxml2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import net.net46.sourcecode.android.lectorxml2.R;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import java.net.URL;
public class LectorXML2Activity extends Activity{
Lista lista = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout vista = new LinearLayout(this);
    vista.setOrientation(1);
    TextView[] nombre;
    TextView[] pagina;
    TextView[] categoria;
    try{
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        URL url = new URL("http://sourcecode.net46.net/android/xml/tecnologies.xml");
        LecturaXML lectura = new LecturaXML();
        xr.setContentHandler(lectura);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    lista = LecturaXML.lista;
    nombre = new TextView[lista.getNombre().size()];
    pagina = new TextView[lista.getNombre().size()];
    categoria = new TextView[lista.getNombre().size()];
    for(int i=0;i<lista.getNombre().size();i++){
        nombre[i] = new TextView(this);
        nombre[i].setText("Nombre: "+lista.getNombre().get(i));
        pagina[i] = new TextView(this);
        pagina[i].setText("Pagina: "+lista.getPagina().get(i));
        categoria[i] = new TextView(this);
        categoria[i].setText("Categoría: "+lista.getCategoria().get(i));
        vista.addView(nombre[i]);
        vista.addView(pagina[i]);
        vista.addView(categoria[i]);
    }
    setContentView(vista);
}
}

//AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.net46.sourcecode.android.lectorxml2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".LectorXML2Activity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

So, what am I missing to make it work properly?, how do I solve that NullPointerException issue? thnx in advance..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize either of these:

```
public static Lista lista = null;
private String valorActual = null;
```

They stay null and are causing you a null pointer exception. You need to initialize them before using them. The following could would work for example:

```
public static Lista lista = new Lista();
private String valorActual = "";
```

Comment: greetings to Urbana, IL.. Yup, that solved the NullPointer issue, still a blank screen with no results

Comment: Step through your code using break points to see what it as actually happening.  It should explain your empty data.